# Why spark tell me “ name 'sqlContext' is not defined ”, how can I use sqlContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to run example of spark-ml, but

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql 

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingQueueStream")    
training = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
(1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
(0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
(0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
(1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])
```

cannot run because terminal tells me that

```
NameError: name 'SQLContext' is not defined
```

Why this happened? How can I solve it?

Comment: Because it is not defined.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Apache Spark 1.x line (i.e. prior to Apache Spark 2.0), to access the `sqlContext`, you would need to import the `sqlContext`; i.e.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

If you're using Apache Spark 2.0, you can just the `Spark Session` directly instead.  Therefore your code will be

```
training = spark.createDataFrame(...)
```

For more information, please refer to the [Spark SQL Programing Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't address the issue (not defined variable) Not that this question makes sense at all.

Comment: Makes sense - I forgot in my edits to call out that the `sqlContext` was missing.  Updated the response.

Comment: It is still not enough if it is not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Basics").getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.range(0,10)
```

Above piece of code will solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).